# How to get ssh2_exec output formatted as I get in linux shell

Tags: php, linux, windows, ssh

I have a php script on a windows server in which some code makes a call to a linux server through ssh protocol and launch a command to execute another php script on it, that is:

```
$connection_portalemis = ssh2_connect('192.168.34.77', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection_portalemis, 'usr', 'pwd');
$controllikd4 = ssh2_exec($connection_portalemis, '/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/php/kd4check_new/controllikd4.php');
stream_set_blocking($controllikd4,true);

$controlliSOA = stream_get_contents($controllikd4);
```

If I print the variable $controlliSOA I get the output in a whole string like this (sorry for the italian):

```
Data esecuzione script: Thu, 26 Jan 2023 15:03:08 +0100 - Eventi di offline relativi ad agent ITCAM for SOA rilevati nelle ultime 24 ore: Server/Alias: WEBINPS15 Data Inizio: 2023-01-25 00:09:40 Data Fine: 2023-01-25 00:14:46 Data Inizio: 2023-01-25 21:49:40 Data Fine: 2023-01-25 21:51:16 Data Inizio: 2023-01-26 00:09:40 Data Fine: 2023-01-26 00:11:16 - Nessun server con agent ITCAM for SOA messo in manutenzione nelle ultime 24 ore - Server che non hanno storicizzato eventi nella giornata di ieri nella tabella Services_Inventory_610: ADLIVCYCES4-P1 ADLIVCYCES4-P2 WEBINPS04 WEBINPS10 WEBINPS121 WEBINPS122 WEBINPS15 WEBINPS60 - Server di cui non e' registrato traffico da piu' di 31 giorni nella tabella Services_Inventory_610: ADLIVCYCES4-P1 ADLIVCYCES4-P2 WEBINPS121 WEBINPS122 - Tutti gli hostname corrispondono ai server attestati su ITM - Controllo della retention per le tabelle ITCAM (SOA e TT): Nessun evento presente nella tabella Services_Inventory_610 precedente al 26/12/2022 Nessun evento presente nella tabella Services_Inventory_ReqID_610 precedente al 26/12/2022 Nessun evento presente nella tabella Fault_Log_Table_610 precedente al 26/12/2022 Nessun evento presente nella tabella Interactions precedente al 11/01/2023 Nessun evento presente nella tabella Aggregates precedente al 11/01/2023
```

But if I run the same php script (controllikd4.php) directly on ssh shell of the server linux, I get this formatting:

> Data esecuzione script: Thu, 26 Jan 2023 07:47:10 +0100
>
> - Tutti i server hanno l'agent ITCAM for SOA attivo
> - Eventi di offline relativi ad agent ITCAM for SOA rilevati nelle ultime 24 ore:
>
> Server/Alias: WEBINPS15         Data Inizio: 2023-01-25 00:09:40        Data
> Fine: 2023-01-25 00:14:46         Data Inizio: 2023-01-25 21:49:40        Data
> Fine: 2023-01-25 21:51:16         Data Inizio: 2023-01-26 00:09:40        Data
> Fine: 2023-01-26 00:11:16
>
> - Nessun server con agent ITCAM for SOA messo in manutenzione nelle ultime 24 ore
> - Server che non hanno storicizzato eventi nella giornata di ieri nella tabella Services_Inventory_610:
>
> ADLIVCYCES4-P1  ADLIVCYCES4-P2  WEBINPS04   WEBINPS10   WEBINPS121
> WEBINPS122  WEBINPS15   WEBINPS60
>
> - Server di cui non e' registrato traffico da piu' di 31 giorni nella tabella Services_Inventory_610:
>
> ADLIVCYCES4-P1  ADLIVCYCES4-P2  WEBINPS121  WEBINPS122
>
> - Tutti gli hostname corrispondono ai server attestati su ITM
> - Controllo della retention per le tabelle ITCAM (SOA e TT):
>
> Nessun evento presente nella tabella Services_Inventory_610
> precedente al 26/12/2022  Nessun evento presente nella tabella
> Services_Inventory_ReqID_610 precedente al 26/12/2022  Nessun evento
> presente nella tabella Fault_Log_Table_610 precedente al 26/12/2022
> Nessun evento presente nella tabella Interactions precedente al
> 11/01/2023  Nessun evento presente nella tabella Aggregates precedente
> al 11/01/2023

I'd like to know if there is a way to get the second one formatting in the php windows script as I get on linux server, and not a unique line string.

Comment: What you are doing is getting total content at a time using `stream_get_contents`. Try to get line by line using `stream_get_line` . Reference https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-line.php

Comment: It worked fine. I'll proceed with my script. Thank you.